# Calling method from a frame when a button is triggered in other frame

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to call a method from another frame when pressing a button in another frame, the only code I currently have is this + the button in my AddReview.cs (Windows Form Frame)

Method that should be called: (This is located in MainScreen.cs)

```
public void GetTrackLayout()
        {
            TrackInformation t = new TrackInformation(lblMainScreen_Username.Text, cBMainScreen_Search.SelectedValue.ToString());

            fPanelUpperMainScreen.Controls.Add(t);

            int valueInt = int.Parse(cBMainScreen_Search.SelectedValue.ToString());

            t.pbTrackInformation_image.ImageLocation = tr.GetTrack(valueInt).trackPicture;

            t.lblTrackInformation_Title.Text = tr.GetTrack(valueInt).title;
            t.lblTrackInformation_RevType.Text = "Track".ToUpper();

            var reviews = rr.GetMatchingReviewsTrack(valueInt);

            t.lblTrackInformation_Count.Text = reviews.Count().ToString();

            foreach (var review in reviews)
            {
                UserControl1 u = new UserControl1();
                u.lblUser.Text = review.username;
                u.lblComment.Text = review.comments;
                u.lblDate.Text = review.date;
                u.lblRating.Text = review.rating.ToString();
                t.fpTrackInformation_Reviews.Controls.Add(u);
            }
        }
```

On my MainScreen.cs I've added a User Control which is called TrackInformation.cs (not much code to show here, hence why I am not posting it) and in this layout the button that Add the review is available.

Comment: Do you mean "form" rather than "frame"? Or do you mean "user control"? And what does "and in this layout the button that Add the review is available." mean???

Answer (score 0):

You can create an event in your `AddReview` form:

```
partial class AddReview : Form
{
    public event EventHandler SpecialButtonClicked;

    public AddReview()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Normally you'd hook this up in the Designer, but for the sake of
        // illustration, I show the subscription here
        button1.Click += button1_Click;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = SpecialButtonClicked;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}

partial class MainScreen : Form
{
    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        AddReview addReview = new AddReview();

        addReview.SpecialButtonClicked += (sender, e) => GetTrackLayout();
        addReview.Show();
    }
}
```

In other words, the `AddReview` form exposes an event that the `MainScreen` form can subscribe to. When the button is clicked, the `AddReview` form raises the event. When you create the `AddReview` form, you subscribe to it and call your method in the handler.